# When are OpenGL object names ever zero? Or, does zero ever have semantics?

Tags: opengl

I have been wondering for a while: OpenGL object "names", integers generated by glGenTextures etc, seem to never be zero, so I use zero to indicate uninitialised handles and check for errors. So far it's been okay.

I also am told that it is good practice to call glBind*(0) after you're done with an object to make sure that lingering bound objects are not accidentally manipulated afterwards. Sounds sensible.

Are there any situations in which an OpenGL object ID would be zero, making my tests invalid, or when using zero in this way would have surprising effects because it doesn't refer to a non-object?

P.S. Is there a symbolic name for zero-as-a-non-object?

P.P.S. Are there ever going to be performance penalties for heavy use of binding/unbinding pattern? (There are some parts of code which, due to encapsulation, have mostly redundant re-bindings.)

Comment: "*Is there a symbolic name for zero-as-a-non-object?*" What does that mean? Zero is *Zero*; how can it have a "symbolic name"?

Comment: NULL is defined as zero, for example. So is EXIT_SUCCESS, GL_NO_ERROR...

Comment: No, there is no enumerator name for object 0. Also, NULL is *not* "defined as zero". It is defined as "an implementation-defined C ++ null pointer constant." That *could* be zero, but it *could* be something else too. If you are relying on NULL to be zero, then you're relying on non-standard behavior.

Comment: NULL *is* defined as zero, in my implementation. I'm not wrong, you're just being obtuse. Way to miss the point entirely.

Comment: Different kinds of null: ((void*)0) , ((uint32_t*)0) , ((char*)0) etc.

Answer (score 9):

From the [OpenGL 4.4 Core Profile Specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec44.core.pdf):

> Each object type has a corresponding name space. Names of objects are represented by unsigned integers of type uint. The name zero is reserved by the GL;
>   for some object types, zero names a default object of that type, and in others zero
>   will never correspond to an actual instance of that object type.

You can rely on the name-generating functions (e.g. `GenBuffers`) to never return zero as a generated name.  You can use zero to represent “no object”.

Comment: Is there an at-a-glance list of types for which zero is a default object, and types for which zero is invalid?

Comment: I didn't notice one, but I didn't skim the entire spec.

Answer (score 2):

Texture name zero is a reserved texture name, whenever you delete a texture it is as if it were bound to texture name zero.  So in this case, it is sort of a special texture name that is always in use.

`glGenTextures()` only retrieves names that are currently not being used and since zero is in use, you should never get it as a valid name.

Note however, using `glIsTexture` on zero will return false, so it is technically not recognized as a texture.

Comment: Any exceptions other than Textures?

Comment: There are plenty of things in opengl that reserves zero for something, in most cases you can assume that a return 'Name' of zero means something is wrong.  You can always try `glGetError` to retrieve any error messages when you get a zero name.

Answer (score 1):

Most functions that check validity of a GL object ([glIsTexture](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glIsTexture.xml), [glIsBuffer](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glIsBuffer.xml), etc.) return GL_FALSE when given a value of 0. Therefore, to answer your first question I don't think your tests will be broken.

As for #2, yes. Redundantly binding/unbinding things MAY result in performance degradation depending on the drivers and the object being bound/unbound. In general, for performance reasons - it is better to avoid state changes (redundant or otherwise) in OpenGL.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any situations in which an OpenGL object ID would be zero, making my tests invalid, or when using zero in this way would have surprising effects because it doesn't refer to a non-object?

Binding object zero afterwards will never make your code invalid, unless later code still expects the object to be bound. As for any surprising effects, as long as you don't actually use object zero for anything, as long as you're not performing any operations on that object, you're fine.

That being said, here is a comprehensive list of all OpenGL Objects who's object zero is not a non-object:

- Framebuffer objects. Zero is the default framebuffer, which is treated very specially from non-default framebuffers. You're probably going to need to deliberately use this default object at some point ;)
- Vertex array objects, but *only* in compatibility OpenGL. In a core profile, VAO zero is not a valid object.
- Transform Feedback objects, grandfathered in from pre-GL-4.x functionality.
- Texture objects. These objects behave in a very strange and bizarre way, very much unlike a regular texture object. Never deliberately put data in them; use them only to unbind a texture. That's probably the biggest "surprising effect" you'll see.

> P.P.S. Are there ever going to be performance penalties for heavy use of binding/unbinding pattern? (There are some parts of code which, due to encapsulation, have mostly redundant re-bindings.)

It's possible that this usage pattern could cause performance issues. But if your rendering code is that encapsulated, you'll probably have plenty of other performance problems. Sorting based on state changes for example must be pretty difficult.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any situations in which an OpenGL object ID would be zero, making my tests invalid, or when using zero in this way would have surprising effects because it doesn't refer to a non-object?

Textures.  Binding texture `0` isn't quite the same thing as `glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_[1|2|3]D)`.